# How to update data in activitypointer

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio, dynamics-crm-2011

**How do I programatically update the subject in an activepointerbase?**

I'm getting a message that Create/Update method not allowed in Activity Pointer CRM 2011

I am getting an activitypointer record, and attempting to update it:

```
var activityPointer = xrmServiceContext.ActivityPointerSet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == myGuid);
```

I then attempt to update it:

```
        activityPointer.EntityState = EntityState.Changed;
        organizationService.Update(activityPointer);
```

And I get an exception: **Update method not allowed in Activity Pointer**

[image]

There is a field called **Subject** in the **ActivityPointerBase** table.

**Question:**
**How do I programatically update the subject in an activepointerbase?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Activity pointer is a special type of entity that holds together the common elements of the activity entities (task, email, fax, letter, phone call, etc).

An activity pointer is actually a full fledged activity of a specific type.

[ActivityPointer (activity) entity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327870.aspx)

> The activity pointer (activity) entity represents any activity or task
>   that is performed, or to be performed by a user. An activity is any
>   action for which an entry can be made on a calendar.
>
> Whenever you create an activity record in Microsoft Dynamics 365, a
>   corresponding activity pointer record is created. This indicates that
>   the activity record and the corresponding activity pointer record have
>   the same value for the ActivityId attribute. For example, if you
>   create an Email record, the attribute values of Email.ActivityId and
>   the corresponding ActivityPointer.ActivityId will be the same.

To update the fields in the activity pointer, update the activity that activity pointer relates to. For example with a task:

```
Entity e = new Entity("task");

e.Id = "Your Id Goes Here";
e["subject"] = "Your new subject";

Service.Update(e);
```